# Could not find Turbolinks

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have used the installer from rubyinstaller.org. But I get this error afterwards

> Could not find gem `'turbolinks (~> 5) x86-mingw32'` in any of the gem sources listed in your `Gemfile`.

I have tried some of the advices in the threats with a similar error, but no luck. Can someone guide in the right direction?

My gemfile:

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> git_source(:github) do |repo_name|   repo_name =
>   "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
>   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git" end
>
> # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails' gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
>   # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
>   # Use Puma as the app server gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
>   # Use SCSS for stylesheets gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
>   # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
>   # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported \runtimes
>   # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
>
> # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
>   # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5' gem
>   'turbolinks-source', '~> 5'
>   # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
>   # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
>   # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
>   # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
>   # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
>
> # Use Capistrano for deployment
>   # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
>
> group :development, :test do   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to
>   stop execution and get a debugger console   gem 'byebug', platforms:
>   [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]   # Adds support for Capybara system
>   testing and selenium driver   gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'   gem
>   'selenium-webdriver' end
>
> group :development do   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or
>   by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.   gem 'web-console', '>=
>   3.3.0' end
>
> # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

Comment: can you post the content of Gemfile and what ruby version are you running?  Did you already run `gem install bundler` and then `bundle install`

Comment: Gemfile posted down below, couldn't post it in a comment.

Comment: please don't post info on your question as an answer, but rather EDIT your question to include related info. Also, please try to use the tools / editor correctly, you're making a mess to look at here.